# Submit checked options from a PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, syntax-error

I'm trying to figure out how to send checked options from a series of checkboxes to a text file that keeps track of what has been selected.  The most I have right now is this.

```
<html>
<?php
//Get contents from zmzonSongs.txt file, put into array.
$songList = explode("\n", file_get_contents('zmzonSongs.txt'));

print "Welcome to Zmzon.  Select songs below to add to your library.";
//Print contents as checklist.
foreach($songList as $songs){
    echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />"$songs<br>";
}

?>

</html>
```

I need to send the values of everything that has been checked to a file like myLibrary.txt after the user hits a submit button, but every time I try adding a submit button using the echo command, my entire page stops working and comes up blank.  I'm completely lost.

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Comment: I have no clue how to do that.  I know almost nothing about PHP and this assignment has barely made any sense to me since I started on it.

Comment: @user3308219 another way is check error_log or view source your page.

Comment: Do research on string concatenation, functions, arrays and foreach loops, and you should be able to understand what's happening. Also make sure you understand how PHP runs on the server and HTML on the client. You need a good understanding of these concepts before you move on to file writing.

Comment: I literally don't have time.  This assignment is due soon and we've had barely any exposure to this programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkboxes and submit button should be inside a form and your submit-button is HTML, not PHP.

```
<?php 
    /* Lets set the destination to the same file as the form. (see form action)
     * That means, if someone has submitted the form, there will be data inside 
     * $_POST right now! 
     */
    // var_dump( $_POST );  <-- Can be used to quickly peek inside $_POST

    if ( !empty( $_POST ) )  // Check if there is any data
    {
       save_data_to_file( $_POST ); // pseudo-code (should be replaced by you) 
       echo "success!";  // A success message perhaps?
       exit();  // Stop here to not display the form below.
    }

    // If we come this far, it means the form has not been submitted. 
    // So lets display the form!

    // You can have this line first in the file, or later, 
    // as long as you do this before you try to use it in your checkboxes.
    $songList = explode("\n", file_get_contents('zmzonSongs.txt'));
?>

<h1>Welcome to Zmzon.  Select songs below to add to your library</h1>
<form action="thisfile.php" method="POST"> 
    <?php 
        // See, you can jump between PHP and HTML whenever you want.
        foreach($songList as $songs){ 
            echo "<input type='checkbox' ... ><br>";
        }
    ?>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You can send the data to another page or the same page, decided by "action". 
The data will be inside a variable $_POST or $_GET (depending on what sending method you choose.)

An easy way to look at those global variables is to use var_dump(). For example:

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

*updated again*

Comment: I don't understand where I'm supposed to add the text file into an array.  Is it supposed to be inside the PHP block you've made or outside?  On top of that, I don't understand whether or not I'm using the <input type="checkbox"> thing correctly.  Do I need to use echo with it?  Running my current version gives me checkboxes and the name of whatever song is to be added whenever I run it, but I can't tell if it does anything or not.

Comment: You can add it pretty much anywhere, as long as it's inside PHP-tags and BEFORE you use it.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  This has been the most useful advice I've received so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra quote:

```
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />"$songs<br>";
```

should be

```
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />$songs<br>";
```

or

```
echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />".$songs."<br>";
```

Comment: I fixed that but it's not what I'm trying to do.  I need all of the songs that have been selected like "Artist - Track" written to a file.

Comment: That's a whole other issue which i am sure you could find a tutorial for using Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<form method='post'>
<?php
//Get contents from zmzonSongs.txt file, put into array.
if (!isset ($_POST['songList']))
{
   $songList = explode("\n", file_get_contents('zmzonSongs.txt'));
  print "Welcome to Zmzon.  Select songs below to add to your library.";
  //Print contents as checklist.
  foreach($songList as $songs){
      echo "<br/><input type='checkbox' name='songList[]' value='$songs' />"$songs<br>";
    }
}
else
{
 $songlist = $_POST['songList']; // which is array
// next you write code to update in text file.

}

?>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</html>
```